# android how can I reopen app after clearing data?

Tags: android

I'm trying to clear backup app data when first time user opens app , I used this method when creating activity but app not opening

```
if(!Hawk.isBuilt()){
    Hawk.init(this).build();}
    if(!Hawk.contains(Constants.FIRST_TIME_LAUNCHED2)){
    deleteAppData();

    Hawk.put(Constants.FIRST_TIME_LAUNCHED2,"0");
    }


 private void deleteAppData() {
    try {
        // clearing app data
        if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData();
        } else {
            String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            runtime.exec("pm clear "+packageName);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Palestine is hero